# Get the input channels for the conv2d from previous layer?

Tags: pytorch, conv-neural-network, torchvision

I was wondering if there are many convolutional layers (conv1 --> conv2 ). How can we get the input channels parameter for the conv2 from the conv1 output channel?

```
class MyModel(nn.Module):
  def __init__(self, in_ch, num_features, out_ch2):
    super(MyModel, self).__init__()
    self.conv1 = nn.Conv2D(in_channels,num_features)
    self.conv2 = nn.Conv2D(in_channnels_from_out_channels_of_conv1,out_ch2)
```

Can I get the out_channels from the conv1 layer and use it as in_ch for conv2?

Answer (score 3):

Second parameter of nn.Conv2D constructor is number of output channels:

```
self.conv1 = nn.Conv2D(in_channels,conv1_out_channels)
self.conv2 = nn.Conv2D(conv1_out_channels,out_ch2)
```

as described in the [docs](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html?highlight=conv2d#torch.nn.Conv2d)

Also it available as a property:

```
self.conv1.out_channels
```

Comment: Anton Thanks. I got what I was looking for on pytorch discussions page. [See this](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/get-the-input-channels-for-the-conv2d-from-previous-layer/78510)